# Alias to external address in compound with catchall in mydestinations

Tags: postfix, alias

I have a mail server that accept emails from any domain. This is accomplished by using the following line in Postfix's `main.cf`:

```
mydestination = regexp:/etc/postfix/mydestinations.reg
```

and `mydestinations.reg` looks like this:

```
/^.*/                           OK
```

Now, I want to forward emails to a specific user (e.g. to `admin`) to an external email address. I added the following line to `/etc/aliases`

```
admin: email@externaldomain.com
```

After running `newaliases` and sending an email to `admin` the rule is met, but Postfix tries to deliver the email locally instead of remotely. That leads to the following error message in the Postfix log:

```
status=bounced (unknown user: "email")
```

My guess is, that Postfix assumes that `externaldomain.com` is in its destination since it is configured to accept any domains.

Now my question: **How can I tell Postfix to forward the email to the external domain while keeping the catchall `mydestination` intact?**
Side note: I would like to avoid using virtual aliases if possible.

Comment: You can also modify the regex to exclude the specified domain, would be the simplest solution I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My guess is, that Postfix assumes that externaldomain.com is in its destination since it is configured to accept any domains.

Yep, it's true

> Now my question: How can I tell Postfix to forward the email to the external domain while keeping the catchall mydestination intact?

To override next-hop lookup from postfix, you need to define entry in `transport_maps` **for every external address used in alias**.

```
# main.cf
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/externaladdr

# /etc/postfix/externaladdr
email@externaldomain.com  smtp:externaldomain.com
```

With this entry `smtp:externaldomain.com`, postfix will try to send email with `smtp` transport to the mail server of externaldomain.com.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solution. However, all incoming emails seem to bounce now: `warning: hash:/etc/postfix/externaladdr is unavailable. open database /etc/postfix/externaladdr.db: No such file or directory` and `warning: hash:/etc/postfix/externaladdr lookup error for "incoming@domain.com"` and `warning: transport_maps lookup failure` which leads to the bounce `NOQUEUE: reject: [...]  Temporary lookup failure;`. I created the file `/etc/postfix/externaladdr` exactly like you said and added the line to `main.cf`

Comment: My bad, I omit the important step, `postmap /etc/postfix/externaladdr`. And don't forget to run `postfix reload`

Comment: Yep. the `postmap` was the problem. Now it's working fine. Thanks!